Poor readability of Spreadsheet Editor leftside statistics panel in Geometry Nodes
This is how the Spreadsheet Editor (Dark theme) shows the statistics of Geometry Nodes:

As you can see the Count column values are barely readable (this is my opinion, at least) and I have to go closer the monitor to read the values due to the very low contrast.
I've tried changing the Preference>Themes configuration options and that's what I was able to get:

I could obtain a pure white for the type legend column which makes it perfectly readable, but, unfortunately, I couldn't get much for the value column, even setting it to pure white (compare it to the type legend column).
Is there any reason for this behavior and is there something I can do to obtain the pure white for that column?
PS
I also tried reversing colors (black text on light background) getting a good contrast, but this configuration messes up other panels (Input/Output sockets in Property panel (N) of Geometry Nodes, for example).

To edit the text color in the Spreadsheet, Edit the Spreadsheet Theme.
Open the Theme Space dropdown and change the Text color:

Edit: I now realize that this isn't the text you asked about. Maybe this answer will be of use to someone. The color of the numbers you asked about don't appear to be editable.
